# Get count with having particular value associated with unique id

Tags: mysql, uniqueidentifier

I Have below mentioned table:

```
ID       Value
U-1      ACB
U-1      ART
U-1      DDD
U-2      ACB
U-2      DDD
U-3      XCC
U-3      DFC
```

I want to fetch those rows where `Value` is `DDD` but total count of unique `ID` is <3.

Required Output:

```
ID       Value
U-2      ACB
U-2      DDD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a self join to same table, Inner query will calculate count per id and filter rows where count is less than 3

```
select a.*
from table1 a
join (
    select id, count(*) total
    from table1
    group by id
    having total < 3
    and sum(`Value` = 'DDD') > 0
) t using(id);
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/BVI26083)

OR

```
select a.*
from table1 a
where  (
    select count(*)
    from table1
    where ID = a.ID 
    having sum(`Value` = 'DDD') > 0
) < 3
```

but i prefer join approach

[updated demo](http://rextester.com/FXG70429)

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid I want to Include `Vaule` = `DDD` other wise it give me wrong output.

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid Modified the question for better understanding.

Comment: @Jupiter Could you check the answer posted by me if it works for you?

Comment: @Jupiter which mysql version you are running ? I have tested on 5.7 and [8.0](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mFYkA75dnhhjyUb5rgjgvz/0) its working fine

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT * FROM sof t1
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM sof t2 WHERE t2.id = t1.id) < 3) as temp2
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM sof WHERE value = 'DDD')
```

The input and output matches for your case at my end atleast.

Demo: http://rextester.com/AZLA7822